# Weird "tapping" out of laptop speaker

Tags: sound, soundcard

My laptop speakers are producing a tapping sound which occurs every ~2seconds and only when there is not other audio playing. When I connect external speakers the tapping is even loder (and still coming from internal speakers). I remember this wasn't happening a while ago.

I have made a recording of it - [SoundCloud stream](http://soundcloud.com/primoz-1/linux-mint-13-sound-tapping/s-Y5EgS).

*lshw* produces this output concerning audio:

```
    *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 14.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
         version: 00
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
         resources: irq:16 memory:fbaf4000-fbaf7fff
```

What can I do to eliminate this sound?

Comment: Have you resolved this or are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: I sold the old laptop and now I have no problems anymore :) I still think it was a software problem though.